# not able to build git hub project on ubuntu system, getting os error host alias not in environment

Tags: python-2.7, ubuntu-16.04

I have one Github project, I cloned it locally using pycharm IDE and installed all the packages to run the project successfully. When I try to build the solution, getting the exception as host alias is not in environment. 
below is the exception detail.

```
`Unhandled exception in thread started by <function fn at 0x7fa22ef08e60>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./runner.py", line 20, in fn
subprocess.call(command.split(" "), cwd = directory)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 523, in call
return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
errread, errwrite)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1343, in _execute_child
raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
BUILD_NUMBER: 1390
FATAL ERROR: FEED_HOST_ALIAS not in environment
BUILD_NUMBER: 1390
FATAL ERROR: FEED_HOST_ALIAS not in environment
BUILD_NUMBER: 1390
FATAL ERROR: FEED_HOST_ALIAS not in environment`
```

OS version: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
Python version: 2.7.10

Comment: Please include listings as textual part of your question. We don't want listings as graphics.

Comment: @AdrianW i have edited the post as per your request, apology for mistake as this was my first question on stack overflow, please have a look of it.

Answer (score 0):

Let's sort things out.

1. this is problem *running* the application. You don't "build" python applications
2. this seems to be a multithreaded application. Therefore there may be output from different threads.
3. in line 20 of your file `./runner.py` you call `subprocess.call()`.
4. that call internally calls some other things (`Popen()` and `_execute_child()`), but the final action is to `raise` an exception telling you `No such file or directory`.
5. since the `subproces.call()` call ends at that point, it is likely that the other output is from another thread. You could search your solution for the string 'FEED_HOST_ALIAS', but my guess is that this message is *not* directly related to the problem.

The problem is, as `subprocess.call()` reports, that the file you are asking to run does not exist. So set a breakpoint in `runner.py` at line 20 and have a look at what is passed as parameters. Then you should find out what happens. PyCharm lets you step into calls, so you might even want to check what happens inside `subprocess.call()` - or place a breakpoint somewhere within `subprocess.py`.